# Firestore bulk insert too slow

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web API developed in PHP that communicates with MySQL. I'm looking to change the database to Firestore, but in MySQL, when I make a bulk insertion of 4500 records, it's almost instantly, but when using Firestore, it takes about 15 minutes.

Any ideas on why is that?

I've tried this 2 codes:

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Spatie\Async\Pool;

/* @var FirestoreClient */
private $database;
/* @var DocumentReference */
private $collectionReference;
```

---

Code 1:

```
$pool = Pool::create();
$graduatesFailed = [];
/** @var Graduate $graduate */
foreach ($graduates as $graduate) {
    $pool[] = async(function () use ($graduate) {
        return $this->collectionReference->add($graduate->jsonSerialize());
    })->catch(function ($e) use ($graduatesFailed, $graduate) {
        array_push($graduatesFailed, $graduate->getUser());
    });
}

await($pool);
```

Code 2:

```
$writeBatch = $this->database->batch();
$count = 0;
$graduatesFraction = array_slice($graduates, 0, 500);
$graduatesFailed = [];
while ($count < count($graduates)) {
    /** @var Graduate $graduate */
    foreach ($graduatesFraction as $graduate) {
        try {
            $count++;
            $writeBatch->create(
                $this->collectionReference->document($graduate->getUser()),
                $graduate->jsonSerialize()
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            array_push($graduatesFailed, $graduate->getUser());
        }
    }
    $writeBatch->commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore is not optimized for heavy write loads.  In fact, it has rate limits for writes, which I suggest that you review in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  It's not really fair to compare Firestore with MySQL in this way.  Firestore is optimized for high read loads at massive scale (think billions of documents per collection) with no work required to scale up, and no performance hits when collections do get massive.